# How can i view my WIFI Password when connected with WPS?

Tags: samsung, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, wifi-password

I connected to my wifi with WPS, and wanted to view the Password later
I looked in
`/data/misc/wifi/rawconf.conf` where all my other wifi (passwords) were but not the one i searched.
And in wpa_supplicant.conf is something like hex (called psk?)
Is there a way to see the password?

Comment: As far as I understand the [WPS process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup) the device never gets the Wifi password it just gets access to the Wifi, hence it can never display it. If you have the PSK you can try to find the matching password using tools like Aircrack-Ng.

Comment: @robert: I do not agree here. The way WPS works is by connecting to the AP without authentication, by checking if PIN or PBC is valid, then by retrieving the password via encrypted messages and disconnecting. It saves the password locally, then it connects again to the AP normally thanks to the password. It should normally be stored where other passwords are, but it is possible that KerbMario's phone has a different implementation.